# Rename a file - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As part of our pipeline I need to rename a file before it gets pushed up to GitHub. Previously this worked when running the Jenkins job on a master node, but now we run them on agents

```
def rename_build_file() {
  print "Append Version Number to File"
  // File without version
  String myFile = "${WORKSPACE_PATH}/release-pipeline/project/dist/myFile.js

  // File with version
  String myFileNew = "${WORKSPACE_PATH}/release-pipeline/project/dist/myfile-1.0.js"

  // Rename File
  new File(myFile).renameTo(new File(myFileNew));
}
```

Within our JenkinsFile we call `helper.rename_build_file()` and this usually works

When i `sshd` onto the agent I found that I had to run `sudo` to manually change a filename (did not have to enter a password), am i to assume that when the Jenkins job is running it's not running as `sudo`

And if that's the case how could i do this running the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with files across multiple agents, you should use pipeline's workflow steps like [`fileExists`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace), [`readFile`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace), and [`writeFile`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace). You can use a combination of these steps to create a new file with the desired name in the current workspace.

```groovy
def sourceFile = "release-pipeline/project/dist/myFile.js"

if (fileExists(file: sourceFile)) {
    def newFile = "release-pipeline/project/dist/myFile-1.0.js"

    writeFile(file: newFile, encoding: "UTF-8", text: readFile(file: sourceFile, encoding: "UTF-8"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just what I needed and also much easier using the pipelines workflow steps :-)

Comment: I am in need of doing an actual rename, not copy/delete, so it would be great if the original question in the title could be answered. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the [File Operations](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-operations/) plugin:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Rename') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                fileOperations([fileCreateOperation(fileName: 'foo', fileContent: '')])
                fileOperations([fileRenameOperation(destination: 'bar', source: 'foo')])
                sh "ls -l"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin has quite a list of supported [file operations](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/).

Comment: It could be just one `fileOperations( [ fileCreateOperation(...), fileRenameOperation(...) ] )` since [`fileOperations`'](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/#fileoperations-file-operations) parameter is an „_**Array / List of Nested Choice of Objects**_“?

Comment: That should work, though I haven't tried it. The focus here is on the _renaming_ step, not the creation.