# Jenkins Pipeline rename file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have to make a change to an existing Jenkins pipeline. I need to rename the file to incorporate the version. The version is already being used in other portions of the script.

This is what I have found but rename-item is not recognized as a command. Where can i find the commands I can use? How to I make this work?

```
stage('Rename') {
    bat """
        rename-item -Path "C:\\temp\\OriginalName.exe" -NewName "OriginalName-${version}.exe"
    """
}
```

TIA

Comment: Have you tried with `powershell` instead of `bat`?

Comment: You can use the `fileRenameOperation` in the [File Operations Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/) to achieve this easily (cross platform).

Comment: I see that file operations plug in is installed but I dont know the syntax to use in this simple case

Comment: Melkjot - that worked.  One more question - How can I embed a variable into a string?  I am passing a param into the next step as :C:\\Temp\originalName-${version}.exe" but it is being taken literally

Comment: Basically try a single quote instead of double quotes for the outer code block. like this:
bat '''
        rename-item -Path "C:\\temp\\OriginalName.exe" -NewName "OriginalName-${version}.exe"
    '''

Comment: see this answer on how to run powershell commands in the pipeline. I would include the function in a class in src : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436370/executing-powershell-command-directly-in-jenkins-pipeline or use powershell(". '.Test.ps1'")  from version 2.28

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your goal is with this question (where to rename the file to) I'd like you to specify your question more.

When you would like to use files across multiple stages, the best way is to upload the file to your Jenkins workspace first, so it gets centralized.

That's why I'm going to make the assumption that you'd like to rename a file in your Jenkins pipeline workspace, so you can use the renamed file in multiple stages.

Now let me give you the code that worked for my Jenkins pipeline. My Jenkins is currently running on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine, with a Linux operating system. Keep this in mind, since the the destination and source in fileOperations might differ to Windows operating system.

Now to use fileOperations, you need to download the Jenkins Plugin "File Operations Plugin". [image: File Operations Plugin]

After downloading the plug-in you can use fileOperations like this to achieve your desired result, here's an example to rename a binary file in your Jenkins pipeline workspace.

**Note** The following code works *if* the file you'd like to rename, exists in the Jenkins workspace of the build before going to this stage.

```
stage('Rename target/hello-world.war to target/hello-world-test.war') {
        steps {
            script {
                fileOperations([
                    fileRenameOperation(
                        destination: 'target/hello-world-test.war',
                        source: 'target/hello-world.war'
                    )
                ])
            }
        }
    }
```

To rename other types of files, please check [File Operations Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/) and [Rename a file - Jenkins - StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479228/rename-a-file-jenkins?rq=4). On the StackOverflow page, scroll down to Gunnar's answer. This one strictly replaces the file in the Jenkins pipeline workspace.

The original answer (the one that is marked green) is not entirely correct in my opinion, since it writes a file with the content of the old file, but the old file with the old name still exists.

Now run a new pipeline build.
We can check if the renaming stage worked by doing the following:

1. Check the Console Output of the particular pipeline job build.
   [image: Rename .war file step in Console Output]
2. Check the Jenkins pipeline workspace of the particular pipeline job build.

[image: Jenkins pipeline workspace of/after the build]

As you can see, the file was replaced successfully in the Jenkins workspace, you can now create other stages that can use this renamed file from the Jenkins workspace!